# Cannot find module './config' mean stack

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, swagger, mean-stack

While trying to connect mongodb with Swagger, it is always 
    showing

> Error: Cannot find module './config'

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
sw = require('swagger-node-express'),
config = require('./config'),
db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function() {
console.log('Database connection error'.red);
});
db.on('connecting', function () {
console.log('Database connecting'.cyan);
});


mongoose.connect(config.db_url, {server: {auto_reconnect: true}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your config file is not in the root directory
It needs to be in the same level with your app.js file